# OnClick function won't work with href="index.php?p="

Tags: php, jquery, onclick

i have made a function with Jquery that changes a links color when i click it... The code works just fine when i link my link to #(hash), but i mix it with php it won't work?

This is my PHP which is working just fine:

```
<?php
    $pages_dir = 'pages';
    if (!empty($_GET['p'])) {
        $pages = scandir($pages_dir, 0);
        unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);
        $p = $_GET['p'];
        if (in_array($p.'.inc.php', $pages)) {
            include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');
        } else {
            echo '******.';
        }
    } else {
        include($pages_dir.'/hjem.inc.php');
    }
?>
```

And my links in my HTML which is working just fine too:

```
href="index.php?p=*********"
```

But now i wanna apply a effect that makes the background-color of my links a different color with i OnClick effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $targetElement = $("*** This is to my links ***");
        $targetElement.click(function() {
            $targetElement.removeClass("changeColor")
            $(this).addClass("changeColor");
    });
});
```

And some css:

```
#****** ul li a:link.changeColor{
    background-color:black;
}
```

The Jquery only works when i href my links to # and i want it to work anyway with my php code of course :)

Comment: if link opens new page will have to parse url or store link clicked in cookie. javascript doesn't maintain state when new page loads. Or use php to add class based on URL

Answer (score 1):

If your going to a new page the jquery is not going to fire because technically it does fire but you are redirected to another page, so you won't see the results.  If you are wanting to change the values of the links on the page that you are redirected to, then you need to use javascript to grab the GET variables passed and create logic there.  Or you can use PHP to grab the GET variables and echo out the correct class you want.

Comment: Im not so familiar with php, can u guys show me some code or a link to a tutorial that can get me on the right way ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't [`a:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3avisited) suit your needs?

Also, note that for this to work, you have to set before a non-transparent background color for your links ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Privacy_and_the_%3avisited_selector#Limits_to_visited_link_styles))

Comment: Im not so familiar with php, can u guys show me some code or a link to a tutorial that can get me on the right way ? :)